# Delivered on today or delivered at today

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Items has been delivered **on** today morning

Items has been delivered **at** today morning

Which is the correct sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Usually what is said is

> Q: When were the items delivered?
>   A: *(The)* items were delivered **this morning**.
>   A: *(The)* items were delivered **in** the morning.

*today* is assumed since other wise you would have said

> yesterday morning
>   Tuesday morning

*On* or *at* are not used in the way you are proposing.

If you are receiving/received a shipment *today*, you would say

> It will be delivered today.
>   It was delivered today.
>   It has been delivered today.

without any prepositions.

Comment: Not quite right on the final example. It should be "It will be delivered today" or "It was delivered today".